# Access to XMLHttpRequest at localhost:3000 from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling' from origin '*' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Server side

```
const App = require('express')();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http').createServer(App);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

App.use(bodyParser.json());
App.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: '*'}));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    // code

});

http.listen(3000, () => {
     console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

Client side

```
var iosocket = io('ws://localhost:3000');
```

I'm trying to make the site "*" communicate with localhost. I tried to use
`App.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: '*'}));`

but nothing.

Comment: You already know of the CORS (Access control allow origin policy). CORS prevents you from communicating / requesting information from other servers unless you have something like an api key. It looks like you already changed your headers to *, but as you said it's not working.
I don't know much about backend so I have found a link for you that might help https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Answer (score 0):

i installed an older version of socket.io and it worked. Thanks everyone!